# Linear Transformation: Multiplying differentiation operator by integration operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$ D $ and $ A $ are given as the following on an interval $ I $ on $ [a,b] $ :

$ D: C^{k+1}(I) \rightarrow C^k(I), Df(x) = f'(x) $ as the operation of differentiation, and

$A:C^k(I)\rightarrow C^{k+1}(I), Af(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(y)dy$.

For my assignment, I am supposed to find $DA$ and $AD$, and then specify what $\mathcal{N}(D), \mathcal{N}(A),\mathcal{R}(D)$ and $\mathcal{R}(A) $ are. I know that and $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{R}$ refer to the null space and range space, respectively.

I am really not sure if I understand the notation of this problem. It is very confusing to me. Could someone point me to a similar example or give me a hint of how to solve this problem, or perhaps some resources on doing these types of problems?

Comment: Not real space, range space

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!